# A parameter is missing. [Parameter ordinal = 1]

Tags: c#, html, sql, parameters, sql-insert

I am coming up with the error, "A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]", in Web Matrix when I try to run the following SQL query:

```
if(IsPost)
{
var db = Database.Open("TheatreBooking");
var update = 
"INSERT INTO Customer ([Customer_First_Name],[Customer_Surname],[Customer_Add_Ln_1],
           [Customer_Add_Ln_2],[Customer_Add_Ln_3],[Customer_Add_Ln_4],[Customer_Postcode],
           [Customer_Tel],[Customer_Email]) VALUES
          (@customer_first_name,@customer_surname,@customer_add_ln_1,
           @customer_add_ln_2,@customer_add_ln_3,@customer_add_ln_4,
          @customer_postcode,@customer_telephone,@customer_email)";
db.Execute(update);
 }
```

It seems to be on the db.execute(update) line, however, I am unsure what my additional parameter should be.

Customer is my table, and it includes the capitalised headings (e.g. Customer_First_Name), and then the values I would like to insert are the non-capitalised (e.g. customer_first_name) which have been entering into a form:

```
<form action="" method ="post" >
        <p>First Name</p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_first_name"> </input> </br>
            <p>Surname</p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_surname"> </input> </br>
             <p>Address</p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_add_ln_1"> </input> </br>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_add_ln_2"> </input> </br>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_add_ln_3"> </input> </br>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_add_ln_4"> </input> </br>
            <p>Postcode</p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_postcode"> </input> </br>
            <p>Telephone</p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_telephone"> </input> </br>
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="text" name ="customer_email"> </input> </br>
            <input type="Submit" name ="Confirm"> </input> 
        </form>
```

The columns are as follows:

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Where you provide values for @customer_first_name etc?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno They are inputted in runtime by the user in a form - see amendment above

Comment: Is the I'd of the table has auto autoincrement property? Or is there another colomn who musn't be null in your table. Could you show all the columns of your table?

Comment: @lnanikian Unfortunately, the option to Auto Increment is disabled, therefore I got rid of Customer_ID (which I organically had) and changed the PK to Customer_Tel on the basis that the user cannot sign up with the same telephone number as someone else. I know that's quite shabby, but the only quick solution I could find for this college project!

Comment: Where do you assign those parameters? Could you use SqlCommand object? If you are not sure with `db.Execute()`.

Comment: I've looked into doing an SqlCommand, but it doesn't find it when I type it... do you know how to declare "using system.data.sqlconnection" in web matrix? that may be my problem, however it doesn't seem to like me declaring it

Comment: How do you retrieve the data after posting? I post an answer.

Comment: @lnanikian using an if(ispost)
if(IsPost)
 {
     
      var customerfirstname = Request["customer_first_name"];
      var customertelephone = Request["customer_telephone"]; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("TheatreBooking"))// I guess "TheatreBooking" is your connectionString 
  {
     connection.Open(); 
      using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) 
      { 
         command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer ([Customer_First_Name],[Customer_Surname],
                            [Customer_Add_Ln_1],[Customer_Add_Ln_2],[Customer_Add_Ln_3],
                            [Customer_Add_Ln_4],[Customer_Postcode], [Customer_Tel],[Customer_Email]) VALUES
                            (@customer_first_name,@customer_surname,@customer_add_ln_1,
                             @customer_add_ln_2,@customer_add_ln_3,@customer_add_ln_4,
                             @customer_postcode,@customer_telephone,@customer_email)"; 

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_first_name",customerfirstname));  
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_surname",customersurname));
        ....// you do the same for the rest (6)as the above line
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
      }
   }
```

If you are missing a library: add `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

I hope it will help you